# Open file manager as root resulting in repeated password requests.. why? Any solution?

Tags: shell-script, files, linux-mint, root

With the new Ubuntu 18.04 base of the Linux Mint 19, I had to change my Bash function in `.bashrc` in order for it to work as follows...

I am running the following **as a user**, it is supposed to ask for password, which it does, but it won't open any file:

```
sunemo() {

    if [ ! -d "${1}" ]
    then
        ( nemo "admin://${PWD}" > /dev/null 2>&1 & )
    else
        absolute_path=$(readlink --canonicalize "${1}")
        ( nemo "admin://${absolute_path}" > /dev/null 2>&1 & )
    fi

}
```

It opens fine in both cases.

But I get this if I try to open any `root` owned file for instance:

[image: password requests]

Comment: Are you running nemo as root? I'm unable to replicate on the same OS if I run as root

Comment: @RobotJohnny No, it is supposed to ask for password, which it does, but it won't open any file.

Comment: have you tried `sudo nemo $x`?

Comment: @RobotJohnny It shall ask for a password in GUI.